# can not open the operations manager database

Tags: scom

I have a problem about SCOM 2012 R2. We have installed that by default and it was working.but today i receivec an error message. I could not find any solve in Microsoft web site and any other techinal web sites.

Here is the error message below as:

OpsMgr Management Configuration Service failed to execute bootstrap work item 'ConfigurationDataProviderInitializeWorkItem' due to the following exception

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "OperationsManager" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'XXX\Scom'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ManagementConfiguration.DataAccessLayer.ConnectionManagementOperation.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ManagementConfiguration.DataAccessLayer.DataAccessOperation.ExecuteSynchronously(Int32 timeoutSeconds, WaitHandle stopWaitHandle)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ManagementConfiguration.CmdbOperations.CmdbDataProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ManagementConfiguration.Engine.ConfigurationDataProviderInitializeWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ManagementConfiguration.Interop.ConfigServiceEngineWorkItem.Execute()
ClientConnectionId:e54564ff-b6ca-4241-b9db-e7922da1e832

Do you have any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that describes your problem and a potential solution.
http://thoughtsonopsmgr.blogspot.ca/2010/03/eventid-26322-database-exception-was.html

Essentially, you should check your database server using SQL Server Management Studio and see if your 'Operational Database' is online and healthy, and you *may* have to do a destructive rebuild.

Good luck!

K

Comment: I tried that but I am receiving the same error. please advise

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this error myself so I can only suggest the usual troubleshooting routes.

Check all your service accounts.  Make sure the passwords haven't changed, or that they aren't disabled.  Also check their group memberships to ensure they do have access to the SQL server.  Specially the Data Access Service Account.

Ensure there is proper connectivity between the Management Server(s) and SQL server.

Ensure Windows firewall isn't getting in the way.  i.e. Port 1433 is open and responding on the SQL server

Lastly, ensure the account you're using to log on to SCOM has access to do so.

Hope this helps.

K